# What Outlook Versions Correspond to the Different Office Mailbox requirement sets?

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-web-addins

How can I find which Outlook build numbers/versions correspond/support the different Mailbox API requirement sets? I have an add-in that requires the API requirement set 1.8 or higher, but I do not know which Outlook versions/build numbers correspond to this API requirement set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for 1.8 in Outlook on Windows with a Microsoft 365 subscription or a retail one-time purchase is available from version 1910 (build 12130.20272). Read more about requirements sets and supported hosts in the [Outlook JavaScript API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets) article.

Note, if your target Exchange server and Outlook client support different requirement sets, then you're restricted to the lower requirement set range. For example, if an add-in is running in Outlook 2016 on Mac (highest requirement set: 1.6) against Exchange 2013 (highest requirement set: 1.1), your add-in is limited to requirement set 1.1.

That's why I'd always recommend using the `Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported` method at runtime to be sure the API is supported.

Comment: Thank you Eugene! This is quite helpful. How did you know that  version 1910 (build 12130.20272) was the version that started supporting 1.8 on Windows Outlook? Just looking for a website that would extensively discuss this info.

Comment: Take a look at the web page mentioned in my post.

Comment: Thanks, sorry about that.